# How to call one actionListener from from actionPerformed of other actionListener?

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener

I have a class called `OpenSavedData` which implements an action listener. I want to call a different action listener after the execution of above without clicking on the menu item.

Comment: Posting some code would help, Also what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Delegate to a common method:

```
private void doSomething() {
    // ...
}

// 1st action listener:
myMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        doSomething();
    }
});

// 2nd action listener:
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // ...
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think from the OP's description `myButton` should `doSomethingElse()` while `myMenuItem` should `doSomething()` **then** `doSomethingElse()`.

Comment: agreed, this is about 1. [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html), 2.  [EventHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase7/docs/api/java/beans/EventHandler.html). 3. redistribute `ActionEvent e` as something against earth gravity, 4. doClick()